# High articulation joints

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, mechanisms, mechanical

Looking for advice or suggestions for high articulation joints (>57°) for an automotive halfshaft.  Peak operating conditions are in the ballpark of ~1000RPM, ~300ft-lb torque.

I've considered u-joints, double cardan joints and rzeppa CVs, but double cardan joints are the only type that appear to be able to hit this target (albeit with some geometry caveats).

Comment: Yup, the double Cardan is what came to mind. Does it pivot through +/- 57 degrees? or is the range of angles smaller?

Comment: The range of angles is +57°, -53° so it's nearly symmetric @PhilSweet

Comment: For someone who stumbles upon this question later, Harris CV joints seem like they could be promising for the application described above. Not actively working on this anymore though.

Animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXyrk9HWctc
Patent: https://patents.google.com/patent/US20170204912A1/en